# How can make exit button appear when admob ads appear?

Tags: android, admob

I put a exit button which can disapear ads if its clicked, but i want to make this button appear when the ads appear and disappear when ads disappear. how can i do that?
this my code to exit ads:

```
Button exit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        exit.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {


                LinearLayout adscontainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Ll);

                View admobAds = (View) findViewById(R.id.adView1);

                adscontainer.removeView(admobAds);

            }
        });
```

this is xml file:

```
  <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/exit" />

<com.google.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/adView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="a150ce9a2bd8"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_span="3"
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this way:

> ```
>     AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView1);
>     adView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
> ```

Comment: thanks for help but my code to close ads is works. i need the code to  make exit button appear when the ads appear and disappear when ads disappear. could you help me?